# Discord.js | TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: discord.js, typeerror

Okay so I'm trying to create a discord bot command (broadcast) and I want to get the args[0] as an ID to the broadcast channel, but when I try it this is what it logs:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\Jakub Sokol\Documents\Coding\Discord Bots\WaterDrop\commands\broadcast.js:8:40)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Jakub Sokol\Documents\Coding\Discord Bots\WaterDrop\index.js:69:11)
    at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\Jakub Sokol\Documents\Coding\Discord Bots\WaterDrop\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\Jakub Sokol\Documents\Coding\Discord Bots\WaterDrop\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\Jakub Sokol\Documents\Coding\Discord Bots\WaterDrop\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:386:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\Jakub Sokol\Documents\Coding\Discord Bots\WaterDrop\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:436:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\Jakub Sokol\Documents\Coding\Discord Bots\WaterDrop\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:293:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\Jakub Sokol\Documents\Coding\Discord Bots\WaterDrop\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:125:16)        
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
```

Here is my code in the command:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'broadcast',
    aliases: ["bc"],
    usage: "[channel id] [message]",
    description: "Broadcasts a message in a channel!",
    execute(client, message, args){

        const bcchannel = parseInt(args[0]);
        const bcchannelsend = client.channels.cache.get(bcchannel);

        if (isNaN(bcchannel)) {
            return message.reply('that doesn\'t seem to be a valid channel ID!');
        } else if(args){
            bcchannelsend.send(args.join(' '));
            }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Cannot read property '0' of undefined` means that `args` is undefined.

You need to define the args variable before using it.

You can do something like this: `const args = message.content.slice(PREFIX.length).trim().split(" ");`

Next time you see this kind of error, make sure to check which variable is affected by the undefined issue. ^

For your index.js file, I should replace:

```js
    try {
        command.execute(message, args);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        message.reply('there was an error trying to execute that command!');
    }
```

By:

```js
    try {
        command.execute(client, message, args);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        message.reply('there was an error trying to execute that command!');
    }
```

Since your execute() method has 3 parameters and not two.

Comment: I already have the args defined in my index.js and when I try it to put it in the command it just says it's already declared. This is a snippet of my index where it already is: 
`client.on('message', message => {
 if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

 const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
 const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();
 const command = client.commands.get(commandName)
  || client.commands.find(cmd => cmd.aliases && cmd.aliases.includes(commandName)); `

Comment: Oh yeah, I see, there is an issue with your execute() method so. Since your args variable came from it. Where are you defining it?

Comment: I don't really understand should I send you the whole index.js ?

Comment: if you can upload it somewhere on pastebin/hastebin ^

Comment: Now it's giving me this error: https://hastebin.com/cesidopaya.js :/