# Discord.js | TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to make a discord bot command (/role) and when I tried the command it worked but when I updated to the latest node version it didn't work and it logged this:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\Jakub Sokol\Documents\Coding\Discord Bots\WaterDrop\commands\role.js:8:34)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Jakub Sokol\Documents\Coding\Discord Bots\WaterDrop\index.js:69:11)
    at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\Jakub Sokol\Documents\Coding\Discord Bots\WaterDrop\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\Jakub Sokol\Documents\Coding\Discord Bots\WaterDrop\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\Jakub Sokol\Documents\Coding\Discord Bots\WaterDrop\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:386:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\Jakub Sokol\Documents\Coding\Discord Bots\WaterDrop\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:436:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\Jakub Sokol\Documents\Coding\Discord Bots\WaterDrop\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:293:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\Jakub Sokol\Documents\Coding\Discord Bots\WaterDrop\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:125:16)        
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
```

And here is the code:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'role',
    description: "Assign yourself a role!",
    usage: "[role]",
    cooldown: 5,
    execute(message, args){

        const roleName = args[0].toLowerCase();
        let takeroles = ['Legend', 'Ultra', 'Onlylegend']

        if(roleName === "legend"){
            message.member.roles.add('734832820710801550').catch(console.error);
            message.reply("gave you the Legend role!");
        } else if(roleName === "ultra"){
            message.member.roles.add('734832749063700550').catch(console.error);
            message.reply("gave you the Ultra role!");
        } else if (roleName === "onlylegend" && message.member.roles.cache.has('734832820710801550')) {
            message.member.roles.add('734836969133309962').catch(console.error);
            message.reply("gave you the Only Legend role!");
        } else if (roleName === "onlylegend" && !message.member.roles.cache.has('734832820710801550')) {
            message.reply("you don't have permission to take that role!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly the same problem as for [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63015319/discord-js-typeerror-cannot-read-property-0-of-undefined)

Comment: I know but I tried working with that and didn't figure out anything.

Answer (score 1):

```
foo.bar;
```

Cannot read property 'bar' of 'foo'
Here, `foo` is undefined.

In your instance, `args[0]` is undefined. You should make some checks to ensure at least one argument is provided via `if (!args.length) return message.reply(...)`

Basically, you must've just typed `!role` instead of `!role legend or whatever`

Comment: I just did that and the same error came out. And I typed `!role legend` not just `!role` :/

Comment: What have you defined `args` as?
console.log args and send the output.
What was the EXACT content of your message?

Comment: This is what came out: https://hastebin.com/rawolavime.js And the exact content of my message was `/role legend`

Comment: What have you defined `args` as?

Comment: This: `const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);`

Comment: Oh I fixed it im really dumb I just had to type this `execute(client, message, args){` instead of this `execute(message, args){`